# Concurrently access MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading

I am creating my first Android app which requires access to MySQL database. My web service is hosted on my web server to allow the app and database to exchange data.

If two users are using the app at the same time, two instances of my program will be running. My PHP script returns a JSON array with some database results in this file on my web server - `http://123.4.56.789/returnBooking.php"`

Will the second customers data overwrite the first customers data, or as two different instances have been created, there will not be a problem?

Also is this thread safe? Should I create a new thread for each new customer?

Comment: All clients on the server will have the impression as if the server is working just for them. They wont interact.

Comment: Whether your database access is concurrency-safe depends entirely on how you've implemented it, but you haven't shown any code, so it's impossible for anyone to tell you whether your code is safe.

Comment: "All clients on the server will have the impression as if the server is working just for them. They wont interact." Does this mean that no overwriting will occur?

Comment: So if client 1 is mid way through executing their PHP script to query the database and then client 2 begins to execute their PHP script, will this override the data required by client 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As zoran404 stated "All clients on the server will have the impression as if the server is working just for them. They wont interact."